# Connect to a remote database running in a Docker container from another container running on different machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am facing the following situation:

I have a docker container (*db*) running a PostgreSQL database on my machine.
Furthermore, currently I have another container (*server*), which can successfully connect to that database from the same machine.

However, what I want is to connect to the *db* database from the *server* container, even if it is running on different machine. How could I do that?

I found this: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+connect+to+remote+postgres+database+from+command+line
and this: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/remote-postgresql-connections#Method-2.3A-Set-up-a-direct-connection.
Both solutions make connection to the machine running the *db* container through ssh. However, I can whitelist only some valid users to be able to ssh to the machine running the *db* container, but not the user (which is the root) of the *server* container.

I hope my question is clear!
Thanks for any help!

p.s.: both containers are defined in a docker-compose file.

Comment: Maybe try to run on the hosts the docker as docker swarm? and then they can talk to each other like a regular docker container? in the docker swarm you can decide on which host the container will run always (maybe there are more options idk)

Comment: Well, I will try that later, but I hope there is another solution without docker swarm. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The remote `server` container would connect back to the database host's DNS name; it'd be the exact same mechanism if the database was in a container or not.  The `db` container does need to make sure to publish ports (`docker run -p`, Compose `ports:`) so it's reachable.

Comment: Can you please add the docker-compose file or files used to setup the two containers, db and server?